# AFNetworking iOS JSON Parsing incorrect in just Lebanon

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

My application has a weird problem. I have a login webservice which is used to authenticate the users, it works well for everyone except for a tester who is in **Lebanon**. For her, the request always fails. It turns out that the json response is not getting parsed for her.

My first guess was that her network place is using a proxy server that converts json to html, so I asked her to switch to cellular network but this isn't solving the problem either.

Please refer to the debug message in the screenshot below.

Any suggestions on what must be wrong will be greatly helpful.

[image: Screen shot 1]
[image: Screen shot 2]

Answer (score 0):

You'd really need the exact data that was received. JSON parsing is totally independent of any localisation. On the other hand, whatever service produced the JSON data may not. There is a good chance that being in the Lebanon, that customer receives non-ASCII data (which should be just fine), while other customers don't. It is possible that the server sends that data not in UTF-8 but say in some Windows encoding. That would be fine for ASCII but not for non-ASCII data. Or it could be that the server figures out that full UTF-8 is needed and not ASCII, and transmits a byte order marker, which is not legal JSON and would likely create the error message that you received.

To reproduce, I'd try to set up things so that non-ASCII data would be used. For example a username or password with non-ASCII data.